# Why does my android app works correctly on AVD by it does not on real device?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have an application in android which gets some information from source code of some websites
it is working well on the emulator but it does not work on my real device (Galaxy S2)

**please notice that it is not working on real device(contrary to previously asked questions)

Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: any details would be appreciated..

Comment: give more data. what's not working exactly. crashlogs etc. Simple answer would be that emulator is not 1 to 1 the same code as in the real device.

Comment: Share any log or code.

Comment: in real device when i proceed to get info from website(by pushing a button) the device hangs and after about 10 seconds it gives me the "unfortunatlely app has stopped" message

Comment: May be you have not given permission in Manifest file.

Comment: I tested the code in emulator, every thing was fine;hence no code was shared. I think the problem can be that the device can't get source code of websites, is it correct?

Comment: @user2012: it has the permission, as i said every thing goes well in emulator.i want to know is there a code that the device can't do it?

Comment: Could you please post the logcat error? It will be easier to answer then.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your real device to Eclipse ? That way you should be able to see the logcat when your program crashes.

Comment: @sheldon: whould you please help me to do that? idon't know how to connect device to eclipse and i didn't worked with logcat.finding errors was always my biggest problme

Comment: Here is the reference. It takes a while to get set up (getting the driver is the critical step) but it works very well for me anyway and I find it very useful: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

I was using 2.3.3 version of OS in avd. the device i have tested my app was 4.
the problem solved using AsynkTask class which should be implemented in apps that they are using os versions greater than 3 when you need to get anysthing from web or connecting to database...

I think this link have a good explanation:

[Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)